# Background process getting killed when its parent is terminated?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, kill

I have code that looks something like this

```
function doTheThing{
  # a potentially infinite while loop...
}
# other stuff...
doTheThing &
trap "kill $!" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Strangely, when I ctrl-C out of the parent process before the loop is done, I get a message that the process doesn't exist. Furthermore, if I get rid of the trap, I can't find the process with a ps -aF. It looks like the background process is getting killed when its parent is terminated, but my understanding was that wasn't supposed to happen. I just want to make sure that I can safely leave out the trap and not leave zombie processes everywhere.

Comment: Control-C kills the entire process group, not just the process.

Comment: A zombie process is a process that has died but its parent hasn't called `wait` yet. If the parent is killed, the zombie gets inherited by `init`, which waits for it.

Comment: So to be clear, you're saying that I won't leave any extra processes lying around if I get rid of the trap?

Comment: What barmar is saying is that if those process are still running, they aren't zombies.  If you use ctrl-C to send SIGINT to the process group, then the children will receive the signal. (But may not terminate.)  But if you send the signal via `kill` from another process or if the parent is terminated for some other reason, they will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09) says that when you type the interrupt character (normally <kbd>Control-C</kbd>) the `SIGINT` is sent to the foreground process group. So as long as the background process is running in the same process group as the script that invoked it, it will receive the signal at the same time as the script process.

Shells generally use process groups to implement job control, and by default this is only enabled in interactive shells, not shells running scripts. There's no standard way to run a function in its own process group, but you could use [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setsid) to run it in a new session, which is an even higher level of grouping than process groups. Then it wouldn't receive the interrupt.

You might still want to write a `trap` command that kills the function on `EXIT`, though.

```
doTheThing&
trap "kill $!" EXIT
```

since exiting the script doesn't automatically kill the rest of the process group.

Comment: Luckily for me, this is a script which launches a long-running dev server.  As far as I know the only ways for the script to end are sigint sigterm, etc, or a segfault / fatal error in the server itself, so I don't think I need to worry